# Find ranges that have #N/A in every cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a bunch of columns that have either random IDs or #N/A. I'm trying to find the rows that have no solutions or have #N/A in all the cells in a range.

If all of the cells in a range have #N/A there is a problem
If at least one of the cells in a range have something other than #N/A, then its good!

In the picture, the red are the columns I am trying to compare and the yellow is the column I'm looking for.

How do I approach this?

[image: Sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the following formula into `A32` (after you enter all the ranges depicted by the pattern in the formula below).

`=SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(C32:E32)),1))+SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(G32:H32)),1))+SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(J32:K32)),1))+SUM(IF(NOT(ISERROR(M32:N32)),1))`

**This is an array formula so, depending on you version of Excel (i.e. older versions), you may nee to press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` simultaneously to make it work correctly.**

In `A32`, you will get a value of zero if all the ranges are `#N/A`. If there are values that are not `#N/A` you will get a value greater than 0 in `A32`

---

If this solves your problem, please select the "check" symbol to mark this answer as a solution to your problem. If it does not solve your problem, please provide details as to where it falls short so we can better help you.

Comment: Thanks Brian! Now I can count the number of rows with no solutions.

Comment: @Brian, general note, in recent versions of Excel you don't need the CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER anymore, so it depends on the version they have (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)

Comment: @Yisroel Tech, thanks for the info. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple formula for this would be to `COUNTIF` the cell is `#N/A`, and then use an `IF` to see if the count equals all the lookup ranges.

In `A2` use something like (if there is a total of 9 lookups) this, and drag fill the formula down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B2:Z2,"#N/A")=9,"Problem","Good")
```